# Replacing default Home Screen Android

Tags: android, android-intent, launcher, intentfilter

in my application I achieved the resul that my app is one of the Home Activity that start when my tablet start.
The code in the android Manifest is the Following:

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
```

The result that i want to achieve is that the user cannot choose if the first activity to start should be the mine activity or the default home activity.
I would to be always mine activity.
There is another thing that i must to do in order to delete the possibility to choose the start activity by user?
Thanks in advance.
Marco

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Afaik you can't do this as it would be a security issue.
You are not supposed to do this if your app is a "normal" app.

Maybe if you are root or if your app is system then you may be able to change that (for example by setting you app as default for the home action) but it would be very very messy

Answer (score 0):

> I would to be always mine activity.

You are welcome to build your own firmware where yours is the only home screen.